# Using an existing VARCHAR column with Room

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to use my existing db with the Android Room.
However, one of my tables have a VARCHAR column.

It seems Room only supports TEXT and not VARCHAR. And sqlite doesn't let to modify column type.

So, is there any way to use the existng table with VARCHAR fields in the Room? Or should I copy the whole table to a new one replacing VARCHAR to TEXT?

Comment: `VARCHAR` isn't a supported type in SQLite, [as far as I can tell](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). It just gets converted into `TEXT` and the length piece (e.g., `VARCHAR(255)`) is ignored. Why would you need to stick with `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Oh, never mind -- I'm guessing that Room won't like your existing schema and therefore won't like any migrations that support it. My guess is that Room isn't going to support `VARCHAR` any time soon, so I suspect that you will need to create a migration that rebuilds the table with `TEXT`.

Comment: Empty migration passes fine but then Room complains about any queries containing the VARCHAR fields. Thank you for your answer, I then believe I shall be copying the table. I should have been using TEXT from the beginning, I guess

Comment: FWIW, the same sort of problem happens with `INT` instead of `INTEGER`. Track [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64822502) to keep tabs on what the Architecture Components team's responses are.

Comment: Same with BOOLEAN for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will definitely need to copy the whole table to a new one and replace VARCHAR by TEXT. And the only way to do it is "outside" room. With the usual SQLite.

Answer (score -2):

You should **not** need to write migration for `VARCHAR` columns. Even though Room uses `TEXT`, it's able to parse `VARCHAR` just fine.